Encountering problem with javascript form validation
Problem: Redirection Not Working After Form Submission
I am working on a registration form in HTML, where users can input their details and submit them. After the form is submitted and validated, I want the user to be redirected to home.html. However, instead of redirecting, I get a blank page. The form seems to submit correctly, and I get a success message, but the redirection doesn't happen as expected. I am using JavaScript to handle the validation and redirection.
I created a register.html page for a registration form in my application. The form is displayed correctly in the browser, and I implemented a validation method for the form. After submitting the form, I successfully create an account on the site and see a "successful authentication" message. However, I am redirected to a blank page instead of being redirected to home.html, even though I have added the following code to redirect:
window.location.href = "home.html";.
I have checked that the path to home.html is correct, and there are no errors in the browser's console.
Expanded Issue for Stack Overflow:
I am working on a registration form in an HTML page (register.html). I have a form for registering a user, and once the form is successfully submitted (after validation), I want to redirect the user to a home.html page, which is the homepage of my application.
I have used the JavaScript code window.location.href = "home.html"; to handle the redirection. When the user submits the form, the message indicating successful registration or authentication appears, but instead of redirecting to the homepage (home.html), the browser stays on a blank page.
Here are the things I have already checked:
Correct Path:
I have verified that the path to home.html is correct, and the file is in the same directory as register.html.
No Errors in Console:
There are no errors in the browser's console. I have checked the console and confirmed that there are no issues that would prevent the JavaScript from running.
Validation Method:
I am using a JavaScript function for form validation that runs on the submit event. The function is working correctly, and the message confirming successful registration shows up when the form is submitted.
Here is the HTML form I am using:
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm(event)">
    <div>
        <label for="Nume">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="nume" id="nume" placeholder="Enter your first name" required>            
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Prenume">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="prenume" id="prenume" placeholder="Enter your last name" required>            
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="telefon">Phone</label>
        <input type="tel" name="telefon" id="tel" placeholder="Enter your phone number" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="parola" id="pass" placeholder="Enter your password" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Confirmare_parola">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="Confirmare_parola" id="confirmpass" placeholder="Confirm your password" required>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="submitregister" value="Create your account in the application!">
</form>
function validateForm(event) {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("nume").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("prenume").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("tel").value;
    var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("confirmpass").value;

    const phoneRegex = /^07\d{8}$/;
    const passwordRegex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{6,}$/;

    const messages = [];

    if (firstName == "" || lastName == "" || email == "" || password == "" || phone == "" || confirmPassword == "") {
        messages.push("All fields are mandatory.");
        return false;
    }

    // Other validation checks go here...

    alert("Authentication successful!");
    window.location.href = "home.html"; // Redirecting the user
}


Your window.location.href = "home.html"; command will execute before the form is submitted to the server by the browser. But then it will be cancelled by the form submission event. You can see this easily yourself if you watch the Network tool in your browser's Developer Tools while submitting the form. So the form will be submitted and then (presumably, since we can't see it here) the script which processes the form does not output anything - or perhaps it errors.

If you want to redirect after you've submitted the form, it would make a lot more sense to do that in the PHP script, once the code which processes the form has completed its work.
